# Data mistmatch error when inserting into a database

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to insert these values into an ms database but I get a data mismatch error

Here is the code

```
    If DbConnect() Then
        Dim SQLCmd As New OleDbCommand

        Dim dateafterconversion As String = datcurrentdate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
        Dim dateafterconversion2 As String = datDuedate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")




        If CurrentRentalID = -1 Then
            With SQLCmd
                .Connection = cn
                .CommandText = "Insert into Tbl_Rental(CustomerID, StaffID, DateOfHire, DateOfReturn, Noofdays, Customer_firstname, Customer_lastname)"
                .CommandText &= " Values (@CustomerID, @StaffID, @DateOfHire, @DateOfReturn, @Noofdays, @Customer_firstname, @Customer_lastname)"
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", txt_Customerid_Rental.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@StaffID", txtStaffID.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfHire", dateafterconversion)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfReturn", dateafterconversion2)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Customer_firstname", txtfirstname_rental.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Customer_lastname", txtlastname_rental.Text)





                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Noofdays", days)


                .ExecuteNonQuery()

                .CommandText = "Select @@Identity"
                CurrentRentalID = .ExecuteScalar
                txtOrderID.Text = CurrentRentalID
```

I think the problem lies with the Customer_firstname and Customer_lastname's When I remove them it works. I've checked the spelling of them in the database and they match so I don't quite know what the problem is

Any help would be appreciated 
thanks

Comment: Access does not use named parameters.  You can use them, but they have to be in the correct order as they appear in the sql string.  @Noofdays is not in the correct order.

Comment: Oh yeah that worked cheers mate